# get image snapshot/thumbnails from a video url in angular

Tags: angular, video, html5-video, thumbnails

I am working on an angular project. I am getting a list of URLs pointing to a video file in an S3 bucket and then show them in a list. but I only want to show the thumbnails of those videos. are there any libraries specific to angular that do this? can extract the thumbnail from the first few frames of the video and then display it. only looking for a frontend solution

Comment: This may be useful to you - https://stackblitz.com/edit/generate-video-file-thumbnail

Comment: How is the Video API and Canvas API not enough? Any library would be using those API's anyway, so skip the library loading part and just capture your own video to canvas. Many tutorials online. You could even code a utility to access each video file and auto-save a jpeg of some frame. Then you'll have a bunch of jpg files to use as thumbnail of each video link. Or else just generate in real-time by creating multiple `imagedata` that be put to Canvas or Image tags.

Comment: @VC.One can you show me what that solution looks like

Comment: Where are you stuck? I don't use Angular I only know regular Javascript but can advise if you're stuck. To draw video frames, the video must be on same server so in your case: either **enable CORS on the Amazon S3 server** settings or else use PHP to read the file on S3 server (then Javascript thinks video file is from same server as HTML since its accessed via PHP script, it won't know the PHP script itself is actually getting data from some external S3 server)... If you can't use PHP you'll have to download every video (first few megabytes) and prepare thumbnail images from there.